# Can you put binary bytes into a ByteArray in python as ints

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, byte, binary-data

we want to use the binary representation of the number into the bytes array.

When i put a binary 8 bit chunk of code into a Byte Array. The only possible to input that as string as far as i know.
What i want to be able to do is put this 8 bit binary chunk into the array and when called (as a print) it would output the real number.

example:

***variable = bin(255)***

(if i print the result by it'self in a normal statement it comes out as the real number not the bin number i.e *print(0b11111111)* comes out as *255*)

it will not allow for me to put it in a byte array like so:
***bytesBit = bytearray([variable])***.

But it will allow: ***bytesBit = bytearray(variable, "utf-8")***.

But because it's a string it does when using *print(bytesBit[0])* it will only print the encoded 0 as "48" instead of the integer interpretation of the binary number. How am i able to do this using python?

The excuse for needing to do this is because instead of dividing a over 255 character until it is below 255. We instead split the binary in two and put them together in an outside program. I.E 16 bit int into two 8 bit ints to fit into the byte array.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you would expect to get out for a few different inputs?

Comment: Why do you want to store the string representation (`bin()`) of your numbers instead of the numbers itself? So just use `bytesBit = bytearray([255])`. When storing your 16bit numbers you need to make sure to maintain their endianess as well.